# How to call any url from aspx page?

Tags: asp.net, html

I have one .aspx page and inside that page I want to call third party url and I should include the content from that url.
I can achive this by using iframe but i am restricted to not to use iframe.

Ex:

```
    <body>
         my content ......
         ..................
         <Video><url="www.yamaha.com\learnPiano">  Thirdparty video get played here      </url>           </Video>
         .................
          ..................... my content .... 
    </body>
```

Comment: Well, unless you remove this requirement I am afraid that you will be left with it. Also you could have provided a little more details about the site you are trying to embed.

Comment: jQuery Ajax? http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 1):

Look into WebRequest and WebResponse.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on the server side.  Add an ASP:Literal control to your page and name it "OtherContent" for example.

```
var webRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
var webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
if (webResponse != null)
{
  var responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
  if (responseStream != null)
  {
    var streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
    var pageSource = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    OtherContent.Text = pageSource;
  }
}
```

Comment: That would be one way to do it but unfortunately all related resources such as CSS, javascript, images, etc... simply won't be loaded and chances are this HTML fragment that will be injected into the DOM will look ugly and probably not work as expected.

Comment: True.  The real solution to those problems is to use an iframe.  Or embed the video object and just change the URL to the video, if that's all that the OP is really after.